# Tracking flash application packets

Tags: c++, flash, sockets

I have this flash application that opens a socket connection with a server. What I need to do is to read packets sent and received byt he application to write a sort of "history" ( in WIndows).
Now, questions are:

1. How is the simplest way to do it? Application hooking? Load the flash application in my application and take control over it? No packet sniffing allowed.
2. Is it possible to do it in C++, or you think it's better to use another programming language? My first choice was java, but it seems that do it is troublesome...

Comment: Is it a rich client or does it run in the browser? Do you need to do this on the client machine or on the server?  Is this flash application your own, and do you have access to the source code? How about the server?

Comment: The flash application runs in the browser, but I can load it in my c++ application. I have the client side application, and i want to read data from it. The flash application isn't my own, but if needed i can get access to the source code.

Comment: If you have access to the source code, you could deploy as an AIR application and just write the log file directly from Flash.

Comment: I can access the source code decompiling the swf, but I can't rebuild it, and since the flash application is often updated, i'd have to decompile and rebuild the swf everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it (by far) is to use a socket proxy. The flash application connects to the proxy, the proxy connects to the server and relays streams both ways while logging.

As far as I know, the flash application can only connects to the server where it was donwloaded, so it means you may have to host the flash localy, setting up a little http server.

Take a look at [Socket Workbench](http://www.socketworkbench.com/) for an example of a socket proxy. You can also roll your own with java or c#. c++ seems a bit overkill here.

Answer (score 1):

you can sniffer packets on application level by injecting your code in network calls, check Detours: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/